# Colouring in between two lines in 3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying the fill the space between my lines in 3D.

I have the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class plotting3D(object):
    """
    Class to plot 3d
    """

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cc(self, arg):
        return colorConverter.to_rgba(arg, alpha=0.6)

    def poly3d(self, df):
        """
        Method to create depth of joints plot for GP regression.
        """
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

        which_joints = df.columns
        dix = df.index.values
        zs = [1,4]
        verts = []
        for j in which_joints:
            verts.append(list(zip(dix,df[j])))

        poly = PolyCollection(verts,facecolors=[self.cc('r'), self.cc('g')])
        poly.set_alpha(0.6)
        ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=zs, zdir='y')

        ax.set_ylim([0, 5])
        ax.set_zlim([0, 20])
        ax.set_xlim([0,dix[-1]])
        ax.grid(False)
        ax.set_xlabel('X')
        ax.set_ylabel('Y')
        ax.set_zlabel('Z')

        plt.show()
```

Some synthetic data:

```
k= pd.DataFrame(20*np.random.rand(10,2),columns=['foot','other_foot'])
```

Produces this:

[image]

Now I want to fill the space between the lines and say `z=-30` NOT `z=0` which is what I am trying to change.

`df.index.values` take a values between `0` and say `1000`. And the `ang` dataframe has values ranging from `-30` to `10`.

Hence, I am trying to produce an offset version of this:

[image]

Comment: I guess that you data starts and ends at `z=0` (at least the one at `y~1`), to get it filled from `z=-30` instead of `z=0` you probably have to prepend/append coordinates at `z=-30`.

Comment: Well the range of the data in the z axis is `z=[-30,15]` or something along those ways.

Comment: Yes, but I guess that the start and end points of your data (around `x=0` and `x=3500` are at `z=0`; to get a closed patch, `matplotlib` simply connects them and you get the strange filling pattern. With a minimal working example it would be a lot easier for me to demonstrate what I mean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution to my suggestion in the comments is to use `fill_between`; there you have the possibility to set the lower boundary. `fill_between` returns a `PolyCollection`, so you can add it to the `3d` figure similar to what you are doing now:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

# +/- your data:
z = [0,10,10,-20,10,0]
x = [0,1000,1500,2500,3000,3500]

ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between(x,z,0),   zs=1, zdir='y') # lower boundary z=0
ax.add_collection3d(plt.fill_between(x,z,-30), zs=5, zdir='y') # lower boundary z=-30

ax.set_ylim([0, 5])
ax.set_zlim([-30, 20])
ax.set_xlim([0,3500])
```

[image]

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know how to change facecolor and set alpha for this new regime?

Comment: Do you mean the color and alpha of the filled polygons? You have to pass the arguments (`color='', alpha=''`) to `fill_between()`